# Best Way To Implement Invincibility Frames in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a little flash game and I want to implement invincibility frames, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing it. Essentially, when the player walks over an object, I want to remove a health (I know how to do this) and then have invincibility frames so that the player has time to move off of the object. Something along the lines of

```
if (player.hitTestObject(spikes)) {
    //remove health
    // INVINCIBILITY FRAMES
}
```

Any direction here would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better give some details about your programming style, I mean is your programming style pure as3 or pure stage or using both as3 and stage.
I'm gonna answer your question assuming you're using pure as3 style.
If you want to make your hero invincible for everything instead of just that hitted spike, you should add a public method in your hero's ( or character's) class and a variable to keep track of how much time left to remove invincibility. Something like this

```
public function gotHit(){
 invincibilityTimeLeft=500;//500 is miliseconds, which is a half second edit this as you     wish.
 isInvincible=true;
}
```

then in your game's Event.ENTER_FRAME loop, you should decrease your character's invincibilityTimeLeft according to passed time. When it reaches 0 or below again, you set isInvincible variable of your character as false. I hope you understand what I mean.

Best of lucks.

-Ozan